# Removing paragraph numbering in Koma scrjura

Tags: scrjura

By default the `scrjura` package will automatically number paragraphs.
This can be overcome with `\parnumberfalse`.

My problem is that at each new `\Clause` that I use, I need to write `\parnumberfalse` again.

I have tried to do something like `\usepackage[parnumber=false]{scrjura}` but this does not work.

How can I set a global option so that it stop numbering my paragraphs?

Comment: What's the sense of scrjura if not numbered paragraphs? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: One can like the rest of the formatting but not the numbering of each and every paragraph.
Also, not every legal system uses the same conventions as the German one.

Comment: Well, then get the formatting of scrjura. What are you interested in? Having sections numbered § ...? The idea of scrjura is to have things quite close to scrartcl, except for necessities of German attorneys, such as numbered paragraphs. So let me ask the other way round: which part of the layout differs from scrartcl-class that you would like to have?

Comment: I love that comment, it really helped me understand the whole thing.

I am actually not interested in sections numbered via §... I redefine the command \Clauseformat so that I get “Article 3 ---” instead. But then I struggle with SubClauses that I'd like to have as just “3.1 ---”. But I understand I should maybe redefine everything myself from scrartcl.
I also want the automatic blank skip at the end of each line.

Comment: Ok problem solved with (I am using scrreport because I want the Chapters too) 1/ Redefining \thesection 2/ Redefining \sectionformat 3/ Using parskip. Thanks Keks Dose.

Comment: automatic blank skip: read about parskip in the manual. You get the German manual with 'texdoc scrguide' and the English one with 'texdoc scrguien' on the command line. Instead of redefining clauses better try it with sections and subsections. Here as well the manual is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

In general LaTeX provides a construct

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{<N>}
```

where `<N>` is the highest level for numbered sectioning commands; `\section` is level 1 and `\subparagraph` is level 5.

I don't know about the `scrjura` package but usually putting

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```

in your preamble would stop numbering of `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph`.

Comment: Misunderstanding: We are not talking of \paragraph, but of a feature of scrjura to automagically count every paragraph inside an contract environment. I mean the block of text that ends with an empty line and does not begin with a command.